# How to translate high level entity relationship into schema

Tags: database-design, erd

According to the following articles written by Dr. Chan, we can describe high level entity relationship. (see page-10,11 of doc-A and page9 of doc-B)

•doc-A) English Sentence Structure and Entity-Relationship Diagram.

http://www.maltercorp.com/DrPeterChen/english.pdf

•doc-B) English, Chinese and ER diagrams.

http://www.csc.lsu.edu/~chen/pdf/ER_C.pdf

These articles said ERD is translated from English sentence like below.

-- The product is shipped to the customer.

-- This action “Shipping” is performed by the clerk.

[image: Product shipping]

Then think about another example.

-- The customer is identified their bank card.

-- This action “identifying” is Authenticated by the bank.

-- The bank issues the "bank card" to their "customer" with similar interpretation.

[image: bank-customer relationship]

Now my questions are:

1. How can I express this situation with an ERD?

   Relationship “issue” has possibility to connect with two entities "Bank card" or
   "customer".

   But I don't want to use ternary relationship as a restriction.
2. How can I translate those entities mixed with different dimensions to a database schema?
3. Basically, is it possible to connect to the entity at another level ?
4. Are there any good tools for describing high level entity relationship and generating DDL?

Comment: What is the problem here? You are not allowed to make a ternary relationship?

Comment: There is a kind of issue called “binary relationship vs. ternary  relationship”.
I’ve taken binary relationship in this case because  ternary relationship is more complicated  than binary relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understand this case is at the ninth page from Doc-A:

> *"product" and "customer" are entity types, and "shipped to" is a
>   relationship... the verb "ship" is then converted to a gerund... in
>   other words, the relationship... has been converted into the entity
>   type "shipping"*

Hence, the final third form will have "shipped to" converted to an entity by itself, "shipping".

[image: model at page 10 from Doc-A on its third normal form]

This is necessary because "Shipped to" is a MANY-TO-MANY relationship (although to myself Chen's text is not clear on this).

But, your example does not relate - the relationship "Identified by" is an ONE-TO-MANY (a card belongs to ONE customer / a customer have ONE OR MORE cards issued).

Hence, the model would have the relationship between "Bank" and "Bank card" identified by TWO verbs.

[image: user model on the third normal form, being 'Authenticated by' a single relationship]

Or, making the model *stronger*, to register several authentication events, one may turn "Authenticated by" into a entity by itself, "Authenticating" (to register event date, data shared, etc.).

[image: user model at the third normal form, transformin 'Authenticated by' to the entity 'Authenticating']

Comment: I think Bank card must be in rectangle not in rounded rectangle because Shipping in 1st diagram is gerund but Bank card in 2nd diagram is noun.

Comment: Hm... my bad. Actually I'd better issue 'Authentication', not 'Authenticating'. Rounded rectangles here have no information value. They came rounded just because. I will review my post as soon as I get home.